# Get coordinates from Firebase and plot them on Google Maps and draw route between them

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation

I need to retrieve coordinates from the Firebase database and plot them as markers on Google Maps and draw the route between them. The first code snippet shows the code where the coordinates are retrieved and stored to Double variables

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("location");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                startLatFB = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("startLat").getValue();
                startLonFB = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("startLon").getValue();
                endLatFB = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("endLat").getValue();
                endLonFB = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("endLon").getValue();

                Log.d("startLat", startLatFB.toString());
                Log.d("startLon", startLonFB.toString());
                Log.d("endLat", endLatFB.toString());
                Log.d("endLon", endLonFB.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

However, the first code snippet is inside the OnMapReady Function.
Below shows the second code snippet

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        UiSettings uiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
        uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        //-------------

        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("location");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                startLatFB = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("startLat").getValue();
                startLonFB = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("startLon").getValue();
                endLatFB = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("endLat").getValue();
                endLonFB = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("endLon").getValue();

                Log.d("startLat", startLatFB.toString());
                Log.d("startLon", startLonFB.toString());
                Log.d("endLat", endLatFB.toString());
                Log.d("endLon", endLonFB.toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


                if (markerPoints.size() > 1) {
                    markerPoints.clear();
                    mMap.clear();
                }


                LatLng start_latLng = new LatLng(startLat, startLon);
                LatLng waypoint_latLng = new LatLng(wayPointLat, wayPointLon);
                LatLng end_latLng = new LatLng(endLat, endLon);


                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(start_latLng, 12));

        // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(start_latLng);
                markerPoints.add(end_latLng);


                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                MarkerOptions optionsTwo = new MarkerOptions();


                BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.startlocation);
                BitmapDescriptor icon2 = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.endlocation);

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(start_latLng);
                optionsTwo.position(end_latLng);


                if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
                    options.icon(icon);
                } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
                    options.icon(icon2);
                }

                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                mMap.addMarker(options);
                mMap.addMarker(optionsTwo);




                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if (markerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                    LatLng origin = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(1);


                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest, waypoint);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }

    }
```

My main objective is to get the variables startLatFB, startLonFB, endLatFB, endLonFB from OnDataChanged method and declare it to `LatLng start_latLng` & `LatLng end_latLng`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add your database structure.